# SSKeychain not found for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, sskeychain

I have downloaded and included the SSKeychain files into my iOS project. I am coding with the iOS 6.1 SDK in xcode 4.6. I have used a button to take the username and password UITextFields and store them as a keychain account like so:

```
- (IBAction)button_register {
    [SSKeychain setPassword:username_reg.text forService:@"myapp" account:password_reg.text];
}
```

`button_register` is just the action linked to the register button. And `username_reg` is the UITextField on the registrations screen, and likewise for the `password_reg`.

However, when I go to execute and run my app to see if it will build, I encounter an error like this:

[image]

I have absolutely no idea what this means, anyone with more experience that could enlighten me would be appreciated.

Comment: "I have absolutely no idea what this means" - have you tried googling the error message? That usually helps, especially in the case of such simple errors.

Comment: Yes I did try that of course, I wouldn't be posting here if I hadn't

Comment: Nice. The error message tells you that the `SSKeychain` class is not being linked to your executable. Chances are you haven't added this class to the files to be compiled/linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I hadn't added the files into the compile sources. Fixed.

[linker command failed with exit code 1 - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553409/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-ios)